# How can I execute a console/terminal app with Delphi XE5 FireMonkey and capture the output in OSX and Windows

Tags: delphi

How can I execute a console/terminal app with Delphi XE5 FireMonkey and capture the output in OSX and Windows. I would love to share the same code for both windows based apps.

Comment: You cannot have shared code. You need different code for the two systems.

Comment: What is the code for each system?

Comment: I can do one of the systems, but not both. So I cannot answer. In any case, such code exists in many places already.

Comment: Thanks, I have done this for Windows I have not for Mac?

Comment: You can wrap up the different OS versions and present a single interface to the higher level code. But the low level code needs to be different. If you already know how to do this on Windows, then your question is a Delphi/OSX question. I suggest you re-ask it.  It's also not a FireMonkey question specifically because this is lower level than the FireMonkey framework.

Comment: So in other words, the question should be "How to execute terminal app for OSX from Delphi?"

Answer (score 2):

For OSX:

```
const
  libc = '/usr/lib/libc.dylib';

type
  PIOFile = Pointer;

//Create a new stream connected to a pipe running the given command.
function popen(const Command: PAnsiChar; Modes: PAnsiChar): PIOFile; cdecl;
  external libc name '_popen';

//Close a stream opened by popen and return the status of its child.
function pclose(Stream: PIOFile): Integer; cdecl; external libc name '_pclose';

//Return the EOF indicator for STREAM.
function feof(Stream: PIOFile): Integer; cdecl; external libc name '_feof';

//Read chunks of generic data from STREAM.
function fread(Ptr: Pointer; Size: LongWord; N: LongWord;
  Stream: PIOFile): LongWord; cdecl; external libc name '_fread';

//Wait for a child to die.  When one does, put its status in *STAT_LOC
//and return its process ID.  For errors, return (pid_t) -1.
function wait(__stat_loc: PInteger): Integer; cdecl;
  external libc name '_wait';

procedure ExecCmdine(const CmdLine: string; CmdResult: TStrings);
var
  Output: PIOFile;
  Buffer: PAnsiChar;
  TempString: Ansistring;
  Line: AnsiString;
  BytesRead: Integer;
const
  BufferSize: Integer = 1000;
begin
  TempString := '';
  Output := popen(PAnsiChar(Ansistring(CmdLine)), 'r');
  GetMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
  if Assigned(Output) then
  try
    while feof(Output) = 0 do
    begin
      BytesRead := fread(Buffer, 1, BufferSize, Output);
      SetLength(TempString, Length(TempString) + BytesRead);
      Move(Buffer^, TempString[length(TempString) - (BytesRead - 1)], BytesRead);

      while Pos(#10, TempString) > 0 do
      begin
        Line := Copy(TempString, 1, Pos(#10, TempString) - 1);
        if CmdResult <> nil then
          CmdResult.Add(UTF8ToString(Line));

        TempString := Copy(TempString, Pos(#10, TempString) + 1, Length(TempString));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    pclose(output);
    wait(nil);
    FreeMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
  end;
end;
```